# Insert nested json array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to insert a JSON array into my MySQL database. Here is the format of the array:

```
${
    "customer_id": "1",
    "products":[ {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_qty": "2"
    }, {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_qty": "4"
    }, {
        "product_id": "3",
        "product_qty": "12"
    }, {
        "product_id": "4",
        "product_qty": "22"
    }],
    "order_totalamount": "100"
}
```

I tried inserting the query as below:

```
 <?php
   require("config.inc.php");
   $jsondata = file_get_contents('OrderFormat.json');
    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

   //get the employee details
   $cus_id = $data['customer_id'];
   $product_id = $data['products']['product_id'];
   $product_qty = $data['products']['product_qty'];
   $order_totalamount = $data['order_totalamount'];

        //insert into mysql table
         $sql = "insert into `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,order_totalamount,order_id,order_date) values ($cus_id,$product_id,$product_qty,$order_totalamount,$cus_id,CURDATE())";

        echo $sql;
        //$sql1 = mysql_query($sql);
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
        }
?>
```

Also I decode the JSON data, and foreach loop.

Kindly help me in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to store the values in variables, so $item['product_id'] becomes $product_id.

Also, try with PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Noogic : thanx for your suggestion, but if i am storing values in variable then same problem occure with nested array. because i have multiple product for same cutomer id and amount

Comment: @AnkiiG: No i didn't getting any error but insertion also didn't work.

Comment: @RU_23 will you be able to add full code?

Comment: Do you mean to insert an order id?  If order_id is the primary key on the table, you are repeatedly inserting the customer id as the order id.  You should have unique keys.

Comment: Will you insert all data multiple times ? @RU_23

Comment: @Progrock I have another field for unique key that is autogenerated, Here I have to insert order id, customer id, and product id and product quantity followed by both ids.

Comment: @AnkiiG I am not able to insert any data, If i am sending only one product id and one product quantity then my data is inserted perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below :

```
<?php
//require("config.inc.php");
$jsondata ='{
"customer_id": "1",
"products":[ {
"product_id": "1",
"product_qty": "2"
}, {
"product_id": "2",
"product_qty": "4"
}, {
"product_id": "3",
"product_qty": "12"
}, {
"product_id": "4",
"product_qty": "22"
}],
"order_totalamount": "100"
}';

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//get the employee details
$cus_id = $data['customer_id'];
$order_totalamount = $data['order_totalamount'];
$order_totalamount = $data['order_totalamount'];

foreach($data['products'] as $key => $val)
{
    $product_id = $val['product_id'];
    $product_qty = $val['product_qty'];

    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "insert into `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,order_totalamount,order_id,order_date) values ($cus_id,$product_id,$product_qty,$order_totalamount,$cus_id,CURDATE())";

    echo $sql;
    //$sql1 = mysql_query($sql);
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey it's working properly now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try to normalize your database. Since a row of the `order` table is representing an order, and you can't show arbitrary amount of products in a column(unless you just stringify the array and put it in.)

---

Your JSON appear to be an order. And intuitively, an order is ordered by a customer. On the other hand, a customer could have many orders. So the customer-to-order relation suppose to be a one-to-many relation, which shall be implemented by a foreign key `customer_id` from `order` to `customer`

Followed up by products and orders relation. A product can be shown in many orders. Also, an order could contain many products. Therefore, the product-to-order relation shall be a many-to-many relation. Empirically, you should have another table to maintain the relation. Let say the table `order_product` have two foreign keys `order_id` and `product_id` point to `order` and `product` tables, respectively. In addition, this table should have another column stores product quantity.

---

I have seen your update, there are some errors in your code. Since `'products'` is an array, retrieving product id and product quantity shall like below

```
$product_id = $data['products'][$i]['product_id'];
$product_qty = $data['products'][$i]['product_qty'];
```

Comment: Please leave a comment or a result after you down vote an answer. Meaningless down vote doesn't help to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
    $data = json_decode($json_string);
    $customer_id = $data->customer_id;

    foreach($data->products as $product) // its a array of products you showed in json 
    {
        // insert code here for mysql insert
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$json = '{
    "customer_id": "1",
    "products":[ {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_qty": "2"
    }, {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_qty": "4"
    }, {
        "product_id": "3",
        "product_qty": "12"
    }, {
        "product_id": "4",
        "product_qty": "22"
    }],
    "order_totalamount": "100"
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
$data=$obj->{'products'};
foreach($data as $item){
$sql = "insert into `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,order_totalamount,order_id,order_date) values ($cus_id,".$item->{'product_id'}.",".$item->{'product_qty'}.",$order_totalamount,$cus_id,CURDATE())";

}


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```html
<?php
$json = '{
    "customer_id": "1",
    "products":[ {
        "product_id": "1",
        "product_qty": "2"
    }, {
        "product_id": "2",
        "product_qty": "4"
    }, {
        "product_id": "3",
        "product_qty": "12"
    }, {
        "product_id": "4",
        "product_qty": "22"
    }],
    "order_totalamount": "100"
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
$data=$obj->{'products'};
foreach($data as $item){
$sql = "insert into `order`(cm_id,product_id,product_quantity,order_totalamount,order_id,order_date) values ($cus_id,".$item->{'product_id'}.",".$item->{'product_qty'}.",$order_totalamount,$cus_id,CURDATE())";

}


?>
```